# Cropping rectangular extensions from ROI in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, shapes, extract

I have this image:

[image: This is the image I want to work on]

I want to extract the rectangular extension highlighted below from the whole ROI.

[image: Rectangluar extensions to extract]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57125879/improve-rectangle-contour-detection-in-image-using-opencv) will be an answer.

Comment: No this does't work for me as the rectangles are the part of whole object and doesn't lie at edge so edge detection doesn't differentiate the wanted rectangles with the object.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.
This isn't a free code writing service.
Neither is it a replacement for tutorials or web searches.
Please read [ask]. Then [edit] your question and add the code you've tried so far. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple approach using [morphological operations](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) + contour filtering with `cv2.contourArea()`

---

Otsu's threshold `->` morphological closing + invert `->` result

[image]
[image]
[image]

Code

```
import cv2

# Load image, convert to grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Create kernel and morph close 
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9,9))
close = 255 - cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=5)

# Find contours and filter using contour area
cnts = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 100 and area < 25000:
        cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 4)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('close', close)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```